# Is it possible to use Multistep Forms with different models?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server-2005, ruby-on-rails-3

is it possible to use a Multistep Forms of Ryan Bates with different models? Because i am planning to do so. I would like to use it for my rails 3 app. for the first step, it will be from my Transaction Model, the second step, is another model, because i will be checking/executing a query from my Products model, and the following steps will be coming from Transaction Model again.

would this be possible? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are these two models associated somehow? If so, look at `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, `fields_for`, and Ryan Bates' awesome [nested_form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form).

Comment: yes. they are associated.  and i will be using a cart too. thanks for the idea. i'll try it. :)

Comment: nested_form makes it easy to include associated models in one model's form, and it even allows you to add or delete instances of those associated models from the form. Very cool.

Comment: woah! i must check it out.. X)

Comment: @charlie, so RyanB's screencast of nested_model_form is now a gem? am i right? or it only shows how to use that gem?

Comment: I think the screencast came first, which shows you how to do it from scratch, but it has since been packaged into a gem. It's super handy. I recommend it!

Comment: oh i see. is it also applicable if i use a cart too?

Comment: You mean a checkout cart? I don't see why not.